# How to create Django form with variable number of fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to Django and trying to construct form. This is a survey app where there are many questions.

**Models:**
I have 2 models `Questions` and `Responses`. Responses has 2 fields.
- a `questionid` which is a foreign key on the Question Model's ID 
- a `response` field which is an integer between 1-5.

**Desired Form**
The desired form lists every question in the question model, and then radio-buttons for the numbers 1-3 beneath. There might be 20 questions on a template page, each with 3 radio buttons. This data would be submitted to the response model. There might be more radio buttons in the end, shown 3 for simplicity. Every question will answer on the same 1-3 scale.

What's confusing me is that I need to get the `questions.id` from the `questions` model, but somehow pass that into a `response` modelForm or form. The user shouldn't be able to specify the question.id.

I'm unsure the best way to create a form to accomplish this.

**Attempt 1**

`template.py`

```
<form action="/submit" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for question in questions %}
      <h2>id: {{ question.id }} - {{ question.question_title }}</h2>

      <fieldset id="{{ question.id }}">
        <label>1</label>
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="{{ question.id }}">
        <label>2</label>
        <input type="radio" value="2" name="{{ question.id }}">
        <label>3</label>
        <input type="radio" value="3" name="{{ question.id }}">
      </fieldset>

  {% endfor %}
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in my view save it into the model. But, then for a newbie like me, I don't know how to show form errors, etc.

**Attempt 2:**
I tried to construct a modelForm for a 'response' with this setup:

```
<form action="/submit" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for question in questions %}
      <h2>id: {{ question.id }} - {{ question.question_title }}</h2>

    {{ responseFrom.form }}

  {% endfor %}
  <br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

All the radio buttons conflicted. E.g. selecting radio 1 for question 1 would also see radio 1 selected for every other question. I also couldn't work out how to specify the question.id foreign key for the response model.

How does one go about creating a form with a dynamic number of input fields, that reference an ID from another model?

Can you do this in `form.py` which will support errors and CSRF tags etc?

Comment: With `FormSet`s: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem amazing! Any idea how one would grab the ID from a question model and inject that into the radio-button names?